# Decrease text size if too long

Tags: android

I have a couple textviews, I would like to limit them to a certain visual length, say 50% width of screen. If the text reaches 50% of the screen, I would like to do something to stop it from continuing across the screen. I thought maybe if it hits that limit, to just decrease the textsize for every character so that it fits.

How would I do that... or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to limit the text, or the view itself? I suppose the latter.

You can either look at `android:maxWidth` (which takes several kinds of parameters - pixels, dp, etc.), or you can arrange multiple TextViews in the same row by giving them a weight with `android:weight`. It depends on what your entire layout is like, and how you want your views to relate to each other in size.